# How to use COUNT(*) with GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, count

I'm new in Mysql language and php.
I'm doing a website for my company.
I use this statement **(1)** :

`SELECT *
FROM motocontroltestresult 
WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(id) AS id
             FROM motocontroltestresult 
             WHERE $variable1
             GROUP BY test_name) 
ORDER BY test_result DESC`

to get from my database a list of distinct test name.
What I want to do is **to count** the number of '**Passed**' and '**Failed**' and save it in a variable.
This information is in **test_result**.

I know I can do this :

```
SELECT test_result, count(test_result) FROM motocontroltestresult GROUP by test_result
```

To get something like this :

```
Test Result | Count(test_result)
Passed        365
Failed        60
```

But it gives me all the occurrences. I just want to count with the statement I use **(1)** to get the list of my distinct values ( test_name )

Because in my database, i have several rows with the same test_name, but i only want to count the last.

I just need the statement in Mysql.

**EDIT :**

I will detail more.
In my website I have filter which the user can select. It refers to a library version. After he chose his version, he can see a table with all the tests with this library version.
But in my DB, they are several records with the same test_name. Imagine someone does a test and it fails, and someone after just "pass" this test. I will have 2 records in my DB.
With the statement **(1)**, I can select all the distinct tests. I always select the last test with the value test_result="Passed". I added a columns "**Runs**" where you can see how many times this test had been run.
It works perfectly.

Now i just want to count the number of fails/pass per library. in my code you can see **$variable1**, it's just my library version.

Is there an SQL statement which can give me that ?

Thank you by advance.

Nordine.

Comment: I said "Hello all" but its like when I submitted it was deleted so "Hello". :)

Comment: update  your question add  a proper data sample too and not only the expected  result

Comment: Done. Sorry it was my first post on this website. :)

It's not the expected result, it s what i have atm.

Comment: Yes ! Totally :)